# Can you consume/reuse unsafe .NET types from other packages/dlls in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, unsafe

I am aware that F# does not currently have an unsafe scope built into the language.

If I have an unsafe type (written in C#) and subsequently compiled as a library for reuse in F#, how (conceptually) would I go about using that unsafe type (if at all)?

Comment: You can do "unsafe" with NativeInterop.NativePtr : "Contains operations on native pointers. Use of these operators may result in the generation of unverifiable code." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340434.aspx

Comment: An example of such a type is System.String.  Are you having trouble using System.String in your code?